# How to show a spinner while making an HTTP request (Appcelerator)

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Currently, I am trying to show a spinner while making an HTTP request that will end when the call completes. I have built several different spinners but all stop animation the second the call begins.

```
var spinnerArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    spinnerArray.push('/images/preloaderGif/preloader'+ ("0" + i).slice(-2) + '.gif');
}
$.spinner.images = spinnerArray; 
$.spinner.duration = "200"; 
$.spinner.repeatCount = "0";

spin();

function spin(){
    $.spinner.start();
    callHTTP() //Prewritten function
    Ti.App.addEventListener('callEnd', function(e){
        $.spinner.stop();
    });
}
```

This results in the spinner never appearing. Taking the call out or nesting it within a timeout causes the spinner to spin infinitely, or until the timeout ends.

Is there a way to have the spinner continue to spin through the call?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's a far better & super easy way to show an indicator. Just follow below steps.

1. Download this widget **[Loading Indicator Widget](https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.loading)** & add it to your project in **app->widgets** folder. Create widget folder if it doesn't exist.
2. Add this line `"nl.fokkezb.loading" : "*"` into your **app->config.json** file within `dependencies` dictionary as shown in below screenshot.
   [image]
3. Add this line **`Alloy.Globals.loading = Alloy.createWidget("nl.fokkezb.loading");`** in your **alloy.js** file

Finally, you can use this code to show/hide indicator properly while calling HTTP requests.

```
function callHTTP() {
    if (!Ti.Network.online) {
       return;
    }

    Alloy.Globals.loading.show();

    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onerror : function(e) {
            Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();

        },

        onload : function(e) {
            Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();

           // run your additional code here
        },
    });

    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
}


callHTTP();
```

Using this widget, you won't need to write long, error-prone codes for different projects. Just add this widget & you can show/hide loading indicator with just 2 lines of code.

Remember one thing that XHR **error/success** callbacks are the only places where you can write code to hide the indicators as you can never be sure when the HTTP request will complete.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ActivityIndicator : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator

```
$.activityIndicator.show();
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onerror : function(e) {
        // code
        $.activityIndicator.hide();
    },
    onload : function(e) {
        // code
        $.activityIndicator.hide();
    },
});

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```